# piping the output into a shell script | Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell

I have a case like in which i need to initiate a shell script with a command in the OS Amazon Linux..
The below is the command which i pass through

```
[premkumar@rails-app-5 ~]$ sudo rds-watch-db-logfile fdstaging --log-file-name slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log | ./watch.sh
```

The below is the response..

```
-bash: ./watch.sh: Permission denied
```

Watch.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
URL="https://collectors.sumologic.com/receiver/v1/http/<unique URL string>"
while read data;
do
        curl --data "$data" $URL
done
```

-- end

The reference link is https://www.sumologic.com/2014/07/28/pushing-aws-rds-logs-to-sumo-logic/

Can anyone pls help me? I need to run this shell script with the command. Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't set the executable bit on your script. Try `chmod a+x watch.sh` and try again.

Comment: Or just do `sh ./watch.sh`. No need to modify permissions.